# Why is my Deck not legal for Frontier?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-frontier

I'm using www.deckstats.net to play around with my cards and making different decks. I'm very new to MTG and deck building.

Here is my deck so far:

```
//Lands
4 Dragonskull Summit
10 Mountain
11 Swamp

//Spells
1 Chandra, Pyromaster
1 Cobbled Wings
1 Firecannon Blast
1 Flame Lash
1 Hungry Flames
1 Raise Dead
1 Shadowed Caravel
1 Skulduggery
1 Spreading Rot
1 Thaumatic Compass
2 Untamed Hunger
1 Vanquish the Weak
1 Wrangle

//Creatures
2 Alley Strangler
1 Battle Squadron
1 Bishop of the Bloodstained
1 Blight Keeper
2 Bloodhunter Bat
1 Boggart Brute
1 Dune Beetle
1 Falkenrath Reaver
1 Foundry Street Denizen
1 Goblin Ringleader
2 Gravedigger
1 Nightmare
3 Ruin Rat
1 Rummaging Goblin
1 Sengir Vampire
1 Shivan Dragon
1 Skittering Heartstopper
1 Skymarch Bloodletter
```

[Deckstats](https://deckstats.net/decks/100812/890154-blood-of-the-fold) says this is not a valid Frontier deck...why is this? What cards are illegal?

Comment: The deckstats link was more helpful than the inline list (though I understand the change) deckstats showed the set symbols which told me immediately what cards were illegal.

Comment: @Andrew Link is still in there just moved it down to the last paragraph

Comment: @Malco Ahh missed that

Comment: @Sam, as an observation beyond the legalities, I think you're a little land heavy. 23 lands should work for this deck, and it would bring you to the 60 card minimum, though you still have to remove or replace the two in my answer for format restrictions.

Comment: alright thanks. i'm still in the middle of getting new cards, replacing cards i don't like, and balancing. so it's a little unbalanced and random right now.

Comment: @sam No problem. Deckstats is a good tool, it shows the set symbols by default for the most recent printing of the card, in this case the set symbols for your two illegal cards were the Goblins vs Merfolk dual deck. if it says it's illegal, look at the ones with weird set symbols and check them out.

Comment: @Sam and remember tomorrow is Rivals of Ixalan prerelease. You'll have a few new options soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Goblin Ringleader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoblin%20Ringleader%5d) and [Battle Squadron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBattle%20Squadron%5d) were not printed in anything that's legal in Frontier. Though they do have a recent printing, it's in a dual deck, which does not make it Frontier legal. The only cards that are not in sets since M15 which are Frontier legal are cards in Welcome decks or Planeswalker decks.

Comment: Technically the Planeswalker decks are considered in the set, though their exclusive cards are numbered above the top of the set.